# Pass parameter from Json Httparty to ostruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**I would like to take data from the response is put inside collection**

```
require 'httparty'
require 'ostruct'
require 'nokogiri'

response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/teste')
   #example response   {x:[{"testey":1213,"Testex":"2018-03-07"}]}

collection = [
  OpenStruct.new(
    :testex => '657758',
    :testey => 'CTH6536'
   )
]
```

Comment: Just pass the "splattened" array response `OpenStruct.new(*[{"testey":1213,"Testex":"2018-03-07"}])`.

Comment: This json [{"testey":1213,"Testex":"2018-03-07"}] is an example that comes from the response, i would like a parameter of the response is to pass collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse

```
JSON.parse(response.body, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, adding an explanation would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution**

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/teste')

response['x'].each do |aux|
  @msgx = aux['Testex']
  @msgy = aux['testey']
end

collection = [
  OpenStruct.new(
    :testex => @msgx,
    :testey => @msgy
   )
]
```

Comment: What if you'll get response with 10 fields?

Answer (score 0):

**Your answer is nice Andriy-baran, The problem I have with this method is   "["** 
**response from my response:{x:[{"testey":1213,"Testex":"2018-03-07"}]}**

response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/teste')

> If the answer were so {x:{"testey":1213,"Testex":"2018-03-07"}} would do it

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/teste')
xy = JSON.parse(response.body, object_class: OpenStruct)
puts xy.x.testey
```